# M5Atom with mutex is down

Tags: multithreading, arduino, mutex, esp32

M5Atom Lite with the following code is down after booting.
The M5 continues rebooting after down.

This code is simple test for multi-task and mutex.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
SemaphoreHandle_t xMutex = NULL;
volatile int a = 0;

void subprocess(void *pvParameters)
{
  for (;;)
  {
    if (xSemaphoreTake(xMutex, (portTickType)1000) == pdTRUE)
    {
      Serial.println(2 * a);
      a++;
      xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Begin task with Core 0
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(subprocess, "subprocess", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL, 0);
}

void loop()
{
  if (xSemaphoreTake(xMutex, (portTickType)1000) == pdTRUE)
  {
    Serial.println(2 * a + 1);
    a++;
    xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

M5Atom Lite is a module with ESP32-PICO-D4, Dual Core MCU.

I have the following message via serial monitor.

```
Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 188777542, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
/home/runne/rh/owmoer/kr/uensnpe3r2/-waorrdku/iensop-3l2i-ba-rbduuiilndoe-rl/iebs-pb3u2i-ladredru/iensop-3l2i-ba-rbduuiilndoe-rl/ib--uil/co/eoneidf/frmpotes/s/fueec:14s/ (eQe.ce1en2 (xQeeuive)- assertefvi)-d!
ebrt f) was c
eled a) PC 0xalled 51 oC 0xre 1
ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40084ea0:0x3ffb1f10 0x40085115:0x3ffb1f30 0x40085e51:0x3ffb1f50 0x400d0cc8:0x3ffb1f90 0x400d1f79:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40086125:0x3ffb1fd0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not created the semaphore that you're trying to use. You need to create it first in `setup()`. For example, assuming you want a binary semaphore, created by [`xSemaphoreCreateBinary()`](https://www.freertos.org/xSemaphoreCreateBinary.html):

```
void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  xMutex = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();

  // Begin task with Core 0
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(subprocess, "subprocess", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL, 0);
}
```

Error handling omitted for simplicity.

Comment: Oh! How embarrassing!